# Script to Pull Date From Cell, Reformat it, and use it to Search Drive not working :(

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am making a script to pull the date from a given cell, reformat the date to a mm-dd--yyyy style, and then use that in a "title contains" file search to get a File_ID for referencing on a Vlookup. Unfortunately it is not working, and is returning an error with the formatting date line, but I suspect the problem is elsewhere since that variable works fine in logger. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 function Builder() {
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 1).getValue(); //get the date I want to search for
var final = Utilities.formatDate(cell, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy"); //get the date in the right format
var filesource = DriveApp.searchFiles("title contains '" + final + "' and parents in 'File_ID'"); //search for the date in a folder 
  if(filesource.hasNext() === true){
while(filesource.hasNext()){
    var File = filesource.next();
    var ID = File.getId();
}
  SpreadsheetApp.getSheetbyName(Index).getRange(2, 3).setvalue(ID); //set the value of a certain cell to the string of the file ID I was looking for
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, provide some more information: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the file is set to the correct locale `file -> spreadsheet settings -> general`

Since you are using `MM-dd-yyy` is should be set to United States

Check that the number type of the cell is set to date `format -> number -> date`

When I do the above it works as expected.

[image]